# Computablility of a real number

Tags: real-numbers, computability

Some real number $x \in\mathbb R$ is computable if there is a computable function $f :\mathbb N \to\mathbb Q$ such
that, for all $r \in\mathbb N,$

$$|f(r) − x| ≤ 2^{−r}$$

If $x, y \in R$  and $x$ and $y$ are computable, then prove $x+y$ is computable.

I understand we are supposed to prove $|f(r) − (x+y)| ≤ 2^{−r}$ by defining a function $f$ and then use the fact that $x$ and $y$ are computable to prove it, but I don't get how to start the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Compute $x$ and $y$ to $2^{-(r+1)}$ absolute precision. Then $x+y$ has error at most $2^{-r}$.

Comment: But I dont think we can change the precision of the functions for x and y that are ready defined. Also, that isn't a guaranteed condition that if |f(r) − x| ≤ 2^−r, it is also true for 2^-r-1.

Comment: @CODER1030 $f(r)$ was written. Thus we can feed in the desired precision to $f$.

Comment: Ok but still that isn't a guaranteed condition that if |f(r) − x| ≤ 2^−r, it is also true for 2^-r-1.

Comment: If $f_x$ is the function for $x$ and $f_y$ is the function for $y$ then define $$f_{x+y}(r)=f_x(r+1)+f_y(r+1).$$

Comment: @ParclyTaxel CODER1030 wrote the question.

Comment: Ahh...I understand, I was having difficulty understanding that both x and y have different functions... thanks Thomas

Comment: Yeah...@ParclyTaxel I dont think its the right thing to scrutinize the author of the question. I have given the question some thought and have understood it and if you cant get your point through correctly  I don't think the approach you took to explain it was right.